# can't login to another page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

After clicking login button, it can't redirect to the next page. Here is my "login.php" code.

[image]

and this the next page "staff.php" code.

[image: "staff.php" code]

If i delete the php code in "staff.php", it can redirect to the "staff.php"

Please help me for my final year project.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: You didnt start the session `session_start()` in the second script, until AFTER you attempt to use it.

Comment: If you are using the password in the select query then you must be storing PLAIN TEXT PASSWORDS ... That **Very bad pactice** PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: This also suggests that you are developing without turning on Error Reporting. Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I would also only expect one result from that query! So processing the resultset in a `while` loop is unnecessary and confusing to the next person to look at this script

Comment: You should also have an `exit;` after any `header(;Location: ....)` as a header commend sends a header to the browser it does not stop execution of the script

Answer (score 0):

Currently because the session is not started in the right place in the `login.php` script you are always redirecting back to the `login.php` script

So start the session before using and `$_SESSION` values and it will no longer jump back to the login script

```
start_session();

include 'conn/config.php';

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user']) ){
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
}

//session_start() // remove this
```